# Swift 4 Codable decode array wrapped with qoutes

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable, decodable

Have pretty bad formatted json response from API:

```
[{
   "id": "1",
   "shape": "{
       "coordinates": "[[12.557642081093963,99.95730806607756], [12.558081912207575,99.96078957337888], [12.558469381851197,99.96072520036252], [12.558029551400157,99.9572275998071]]"}"
}]
```

I need to decode this "shape" key to my custom structs, which doesn't seems like a big deal but I have that quotes wrapping the array `"[]"`

so, what I have:

```
public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try container.decode(Identifier.self, forKey: .id)
    shape = try container
        .nestedContainer(keyedBy: ShapeCoordinatesCodingKeys.self, forKey: .shape)
        .decode([[Double]].self, forKey: .coordinates)
        .flatMap {
            $0.count > 1 ? Location(latitude: $0[0], longitude: $0[1]) : nil
    }
}
```

resonably have error

```
"Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a string/data instead."
```

and of corse this call works (made for test purposes only):

```
po try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ShapeCoordinatesCodingKeys.self, forKey: .shape).decode(String.self, forKey: .coordinates)
```

and have this output:

```
"[[12.557642081093963,99.95730806607756], [12.558081912207575,99.96078957337888], [12.558469381851197,99.96072520036252], [12.558029551400157,99.9572275998071]]"
```

so it there any way to decode this String-style-wrapped json array into Swift array using `Codable`?

I managed to do some workaround, it works, but it doesn't seem like a good solution at all. Will post it here, but the question "Is there any way to implement this normally with Codable" is still opened

```
public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Identifier.self, forKey: .id)

        do {
            shape = try container
                .nestedContainer(keyedBy: ShapeCoordinatesCodingKeys.self, forKey: .shape)
                .decode([[Double]].self, forKey: .coordinates)
                .flatMap {
                    $0.count > 1 ? Location(latitude: $0[0], longitude: $0[1]) : nil
            }
        }
        catch {

            guard let coordinatesData = try container
                .nestedContainer(keyedBy: ShapeCoordinatesCodingKeys.self, forKey: .shape)
                .decode(String.self, forKey: .coordinates).data(using: .utf8) else {
                    throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(
                        DecodingError.Context(
                            codingPath: [ShapeCoordinatesCodingKeys.coordinates],
                            debugDescription: "Array or String?"
                        )
                    )
            }

            shape = try JSONDecoder()
                .decode([[Double]].self, from: coordinatesData)
                .flatMap {
                $0.count > 1 ? Location(latitude: $0[0], longitude: $0[1]) : nil
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: because the value of `coordinates` seems a pure `String` not an `Array`, you need to convert that particular `String` value to JSON (if that is supposed to be a _valid_ JSON) and individually decode it.

Comment: @holex this is valid json, but it can't be decoded normally because it's treated as a String, can't blame JSONDecoder here, this is all understandable

Comment: that seems to be deliberately sent as a `String` and not an `Array` (for any kinda reason), that is purely a case on back-end and even if that string is currently formatted as a valid JSON, it is still a raw string from parser's perspective and it could anything else from anytime – obviuously the `JSONEcoder` cannot parse it as the value a raw string, not a decodable structure.

Answer (score 0):

That may give you an idea of how to deal with such `String`:

```
let rawString: String = "[[12.557642081093963,99.95730806607756], [12.558081912207575,99.96078957337888], [12.558469381851197,99.96072520036252], [12.558029551400157,99.9572275998071]]"
```

---

Basically what happens here is that converting the `String` back to `Data` and trying to parse this *new* `data` as a JSON by decoding it into a `[[Double]]`:

```
if let data: Data = rawString.data(using: .utf8) {
    let coordinates: [[Double]]? = try? JSONDecoder().decode([[Double]].self, from: data)
    // yes, it is an array now as I wanted!
}
```

---

***NOTE:** as long as the `String` is supposed to be a valid JSON inside the quotation marks, that will not fail at all. of course, it is quite suspicious why the response contains the JSON only indirectly but you can bridge such situation easily, if you – as I said just above – expect a valid JSON there.*

Comment: It worked for me, I figured this right after this post, but this is doesn't seems like a good solution, but as a workaround it worked, yes. Thank you

Comment: a 'good' solution would be if the backend API sends the data in a nice parsable structure – but that is probably not something you could affect.

Comment: Hi Holex. I hope you are well. Please do not roll back my case (and spelling) fixes - they are legitimate changes. We have a preference for technical writing here. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer, I'm not too bad, thanks – when a change adds nothing to the answer I'll revert them back; no hard feelings.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I appreciate a clear statement of views. My case edits do in fact add something - they add readability and the application of standard English writing rules. I'll try to obtain the opinion of a moderator, and then perhaps I can come back to you in chat? I am keen to oppose this content damage if I can, and I hope I can get you on-side as I do so. My edits are made exclusively for quality reasons.

Comment: @halfer, I appreciate your enthusiasm but please excuse my bluntness as I see no _"content-damage"_ (whatever that means in this particular context) – I can tell you in the last 6 years you are the _second_ person who felt to crusade, whilst 2.1K+ member of this community (incl. moderators and fellow developers) were keen to upvote / downvote my answers for some reasons and other 1.4M+ readers have focused on the technical content instead; fear to say such summary but even if your goal is purely noble (what I won't question at all) you are slightly outnumbered by society here.

Comment: The low bar you are being judged by "society" - if that is what the readership is called - is because most readers do not vote, or sign in, or care, at all. In short - they are not a society in the participative sense. They get their answer, they wade through all manner of low-quality and chatty material if they have to, and leave. Real societies - like the Meta community, SO CVR, dedicated voters/editors - they care about quality, but they are sadly fewer in number than the misleading statistics we all have on our profiles.

Comment: So, I don't doubt you are in earnest when you think people approve of your mobile-phone posting, but I think it is wrong, for the reasons I set out. Since we're chatting here anyway, I'd be interested to know why you do it - do please explain if you will. It's fine in your profile, even if, to my eyes, it is wilfully wrong - but your profile is your business. The material in answers is a shared responsibility and undoing improvements ought to be regarded as vandalism. I will let you know what I can get from a moderator.

Comment: @halfer, as I said, I really appreciate what you'd try to do but at this stage I'd propose not to carry on this conversation and draw the bottom line as it seems you have lost your objectivity here by thinking your single opinion is omnipotent, then you disagree therefore the other one is obviously wrong (sic!), finally arbitrarily redefine _vandalism_ in your favour... not cool – in my view I'd rather see more technical answers from you in your profession than actually harassing other contributors and offing the comment section by completely irrelevant conversations.

Comment: Ah no, "vandalism" is an [established concept](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vandalism) on Stack Overflow (it seems to be used for wanton damage, in the ragequit sense, but also persistent and wilful flouting of writing conventions that harm readability). That's nothing to do with me, except insofar as I agree with the community's understanding of it. Please try to keep your cool - we have had a civil discussion so far.

Comment: @halfer, I highly recomment you to read this material throughly before you carry on contributing here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, and I also gently redirect you to find _low-quality-answers_ what you can edit anytime in your freetime: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts, good luck in future!